# How to test data with R e1071 SVM multiclass

Tags: r, classification, svm, text-classification

First time I'm using R and e1071 package and SVM multiclass! I'm very confused, then. The goal is: if I have a sentence with sunny; it will be classified as "yes" sentence; if I have a sentence with cloud, it will be classified as "maybe", if I have a sentence with rainy; il will be classified ad "no". The true goal is to do some text classification for my research.

I have two files:

- train.csv: a file where there are two columns/Variables one is the
  data, the other is the label.

Example:

```
                  V1    V2
1              sunny   yes
2        sunny sunny   yes
3  sunny rainy sunny   yes
4  sunny cloud sunny   yes
5              rainy    no
6        rainy rainy    no
7  rainy sunny rainy    no
8  rainy cloud rainy    no
9              cloud maybe
10       cloud cloud maybe
11 cloud rainy cloud maybe
12 cloud sunny cloud maybe
```

- test.csv: in this file there are the new data to be classified.

Example:

```
      V1
1  sunny
2  rainy
3  hello
4  cloud
5      a
6      b
7  cloud
8      d
9      e
10     f
11     g
12 hello
```

Following the examples for the iris dataset 
(https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/e1071.pdf and http://rischanlab.github.io/SVM.html)
I created my model and then test the training data in this way:

```
> library(e1071)
> train <- read.csv(file="C:/Users/Stef/Desktop/train.csv", sep = ";", header = FALSE)
> test <- read.csv(file="C:/Users/Stef/Desktop/test.csv", sep = ";", header = FALSE)
> attach(train)
> x <- subset(train, select=-V2)
> y <- V2
> model <- svm(V2 ~ ., data = train, probability=TRUE)
> summary(model)

Call:
svm(formula = V2 ~ ., data = train, probability = TRUE)


Parameters:
   SVM-Type:  C-classification 
 SVM-Kernel:  radial 
       cost:  1 
      gamma:  0.08333333 

Number of Support Vectors:  12

 ( 4 4 4 )


Number of Classes:  3 

Levels: 
 maybe no yes

> pred <- predict(model,x)
> system.time(pred <- predict(model,x))
   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       0 
> table(pred,y)
       y
pred    maybe no yes
  maybe     4  0   0
  no        0  4   0
  yes       0  0   4
> pred
    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12 
  yes   yes   yes   yes    no    no    no    no maybe maybe maybe maybe 
Levels: maybe no yes
```

I think it's ok until now.
Now the question is: what about the test data? I didn't find anything for the test data. Then, I thought that maybe I should test the model with the test data. And I did this:

```
> test
      V1
1  sunny
2  rainy
3  hello
4  cloud
5      a
6      b
7  cloud
8      d
9      e
10     f
11     g
12 hello
> z <- subset(test, select=V1)
> pred <-predict(model,z)
Error in predict.svm(model, z) : test data does not match model !
```

What is wrong here? Can you please explain me how can I test new data using the old train model?
Thank you

**EDIT**

These are the first 5 rows for each file .csv

```
> head(train,5)
                 V1  V2
1             sunny yes
2       sunny sunny yes
3 sunny rainy sunny yes
4 sunny cloud sunny yes
5             rainy  no
> head(test,5)
     V1
1 sunny
2 rainy
3 hello
4 cloud
5     a
```

Comment: can you please provide something like head train.csv and head test.csv? i'm having trouble reconciling your statement that there are two columns with the output you pasted (eg sunny,rainy,sunny,yes)

Comment: @MikePalmice I just edited the question for you :)

Comment: Shouldn't train and test have the same number of columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factors in train and test dataset are different here so you would need to fix it first.

```
library(e1071)
#sample data
train_data <- data.frame(V1 = c("sunny","sunny sunny","rainy","rainy rainy","cloud","cloud cloud"),
                         V2= c("yes","yes","no","no","maybe","maybe"))
test_data <- data.frame(V1 = c("sunny","rainy","hello","cloud"))

#fix levels in train_data & test_data dataset before running model
train_data$ind <- "train"
test_data$ind <- "test"
merged_data <- rbind(train_data[,-grep("V2", colnames(train_data))],test_data)
#train data
train <- merged_data[merged_data$ind=="train",]
train$V2 <- train_data$V2
train <- train[,-grep("ind", colnames(train))]
#test data
test <- merged_data[merged_data$ind=="test",]
test <- data.frame(V1 = test[,-grep("ind", colnames(test))])

#svm model
svm_model <- svm(V2 ~ ., data = train, probability=TRUE)
summary(svm_model)
train_pred <- predict(svm_model,train["V1"])
table(train_pred,train$V2)

#prediction on test data
test$test_pred <- predict(svm_model,test)
test
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Jurafsky pls don't forget to let us know if it helped!

Comment: thank you very much you saved my day! It seems so complicated: what is "rbind"? and should I write all this code everytime or there is something simpler that I can do, on the source file for exemple (the rows and columns layout)

Comment: why should I merge everytime the test and train data?

Comment: Glad that it helped! To answer your question - 1) `rbind` is used to union two dataframes. 2) Why to merge every time? - The requirement of SVM package `e1071` says that factors in 'test' dataset should not be different than what was known to the model during training. So basically by merge (i.e. rbind) we are letting model know all factors in advance. If you check `str(train)` then you'll find more factors than `str(train_data)` because now `train` has factors of both train & test dataset (`rbind` did all magic!). Hope it helps!

Comment: How can I see if there are some classes that are not well classified? Using "table" I can see the partition of the classified classes and features, but how can I see (in the case of sure misclassification), which features has been misclassified? 
And, is there a way to improve (or as I see, "tune") the svm? Thank you again

Comment: 1) `?tune` will give you option to tune your model. e.g.  `tuning_svm_model <- tune.svm(V2 ~ ., data = train, gamma = 2^(-1:1), cost = 2^(2:4)); summary(tuning_svm_model)`. This will give you the optimal value of `cost` and `gamma` which you can pass on to your model like `svm_model <- svm(V2 ~ ., data = train, cost=<tuned_cost>, gamma=<tuned_gamma>, probability=TRUE)`. Important point to note here is that you need to be smart to provide the initial cost & gamma range to `tune.svm`. 2) to see misclassified item in train dataset - `train[train_pred!=train$V2,]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be with your select argument to the subset function - what happens if you just execute `pred<-predict(model,test)`? It's a bit hard to tell whether your original data has two columns (V1,V2) or up to four. Since you trained/initialized the model with `data=train`, I think predicting on test instead of subset(test,) should resolve the issue.

Predict will work on SVM's even if the number of rows in the test set is different than the number of rows the SVM was trained on ... it should be trivial. something like:

```
test.preds<-predict(some.svm, test)
misclassification.rate<-mean(test.preds != test$V2)
```

Comment: Already tested and it doesn't work :( I did in order: pred <-predict(model,test), Error in predict.svm(model, test) : test data does not match model !test.pred<-predict(svm, test)
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "function"
> test.pred<-predict(model, test)
Error in predict.svm(model, test) : test data does not match model !